# Is it legal to give fictional characters titles of real-world government officials?

Tags: united-states, us-federal-government, government-officers, name-title

Is it legal to refer to fictional characters in a video game with titles of real-world government officials, e.g., a Congressman, the President, etc.? I've seen lots of movies where they refer to "Mr. President" as a character in the show, but who bears no relation to the real-world incumbent president. So I think this is fine, but I'd like to know if there are any caveats involved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Impersonating" a government agent for an Alternate Reality Game](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/44993/impersonating-a-government-agent-for-an-alternate-reality-game)

Answer (score 4):

#### It's fine, as long as it's clear that it's fiction

As far as I know, titles such as "Mr. President" aren't specifically restricted in any way. That said, there are a few relevant laws here regarding impersonating government officials or using the seals of government offices.  Generally speaking, they prohibit doing things that are intended to mislead people into thinking that you are part of or otherwise affiliated with the government.

One is [18 U.S. Code § 912](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/912), which states that:

> Whoever falsely assumes or pretends to be an officer or employee acting under the authority of the United States or any department, agency or officer thereof, and acts as such, or in such pretended character demands or obtains any money, paper, document, or thing of value, shall be fined under this title or imprisoned not more than three years, or both.

I'm not entirely clear whether the President or members of Congress are included in "officers" here, but it only criminalizes impersonating such officers for the purpose of fooling someone into doing something for you.

More directly relevant to the Presidency and members of Congress is [18 U.S. Code § 713](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/713), which governs the "Use of likenesses of the great seal of the United States, the seals of the President and Vice President, the seal of the United States Senate, the seal of the United States House of Representatives, and the seal of the United States Congress".

It forbids use of the seals of those offices

> for the purpose of conveying, or in a manner reasonably calculated to convey, a false impression of sponsorship or approval by the Government of the United States or by any department, agency, or instrumentality thereof

For official insignia or uniforms more generally, [18 U.S. Code § 716](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/716) exempts uses that are

> not used or intended to be used to mislead or deceive...[or are] used exclusively for a dramatic presentation, such as a theatrical, film, or television production.

Comment: *"It's fine, as long as it's clear that it's fiction"* As opposed to a non-fiction video game?

Comment: @bdb484 it might somehow, perhaps, imply that it's conveying official messages from or sponsorship by the US government (which _has_ [published a video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America%27s_Army)).

Comment: I don't think that's the case, but even if it did, that's a different argument altogether. Making it clearly fictional doesn't make it clear that it's not an official message, as the government frequently uses fiction to communicate official messages. For instance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxU6n4pAnrU

Comment: @bdb484 Oregon Trail?

Comment: See for example the Merchant Princes series by Charles Stross, which features Donald Rumsfeld behaving badly.

Comment: The use of any official regalia is not a necessary component of the crime.  See [DOJ guidance on what constitutes elements of personation under 18 USC §912](https://www.justice.gov/jm/criminal-resource-manual-1470-false-personation-elements-offenses).  Namely, "**action alone may amount to a false pretense of federal authority**. See Heskett v. United States, 58 F.2d 897, 902 (9th Cir. 1932) (by inquiring about passports, defendants pretended to be federal immigration officers)."

Comment: @grovkin Thanks for the link; that seems clear from the plain text of the law as well, and I didn't intend to imply otherwise.  I'd tried to separate those things in my answer and make it clear which parts referred to actions vs. use of regalia/seals.

Comment: Is there any particular part that's unclear or could be clearer?

Comment: I am not really sure.  I think you added the part about regalia as a by the by.  And I continued along the same train of thought.